# How insert multiple data using array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm a newbie using php CodeIgniter. I can insert the array using php native. but how I can insert array using CodeIgniter, please? help me

I have a program for many checkboxes. if I checked more than 1 or checked all it's just still insert 1 data. its said success but just 1 data. so I want to insert more than 1. how can I do that's code? please fix it

this is my function order code from the controller :

```
public function order()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_sub', 'Id_sub', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $data['title'] = 'Order';
            $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
            $data["home"] = $this->product_model->getAll_join();
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
            $this->load->view('user/order', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $data = [
                'id_sub' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('id_sub', true))
            ];
            $this->db->insert('tbl_order_detail', $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Data berhasil disimpan.
             </div>');
            redirect('user/order');
        }
    }
```

this is my view order code :

```
 <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        $query = $this->db->query("select tbl_referensi.referensi, tbl_sub_kategori.sub, tbl_sub_kategori.id_sub
                                            from tbl_referensi
                                            inner join tbl_sub_kategori
                                            on tbl_referensi.id_ref = tbl_sub_kategori.id_ref
                                            where tbl_referensi.id_ref = $tampil->id_ref;
                                            ");
                                        foreach ($query->result() as $tampil_sub) :
                                            ?>
                                            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" name="id_sub" id="id_sub" value="<?= $tampil_sub->id_sub ?>"> <label for="name" class="mr-4"><?= $tampil_sub->sub ?></label>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

i think the problem is from function order and tag HTML(name=`"id_sub"`) from view order. maybe using id_sub[].
but how? please fix it and help me.

Comment: by using *implode* function

Comment: $data = [
                'id_sub' => implode(',',$this->input->post('id_sub'))
            ];

Comment: is this *id_sub* your table primary key?

Comment: what is data type?

Comment: change data type to varchar

Comment: did you change input name as an array? update your new code here with data structure screen shot

Comment: can i see you table structure ? and could you please print_r the post value?

Comment: I was taking about database table structure

Comment: change varchar size 11 to 255 and try to save

Comment: did you change varchar size?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" name="id_sub[]" id="id_sub" value="<?= $tampil_sub->id_sub ?>"> <label for="name" class="mr-4"><?= $tampil_sub->sub ?></label>
```

and you will get value in controller using

```
$post_data = $this->input->post('id_sub');
foreach ($post_data as $key=>$value) {
  // do your code
}
```

Comment: you can also use batch insert of CI but its advance part of it so you need to save by the traditional method.

Comment: if i put ```id_sub[]``` in view order, its show nothing to do
but if i input ```id_sub``` its work but still 1 data insert not for array. can tell me how my code?

Comment: Have you checked the checkboxes before sending it to the server?An unchecked checkbox will not be sent to the server. Try `id_sub[]` and check all the checkboxes. You can debug your form by putting `var_dump($_POST);` somewhere in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here in html, input name should be an array

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" name="id_sub[]" id="id_sub" value="<?= $tampil_sub->id_sub ?>"> <label for="name" class="mr-4"><?= $tampil_sub->sub ?>
```

Mysql Query:

```
$data = [
          'id_sub' => implode(',',$this->input->post('id_sub'))
        ];
 $this->db->insert('tbl_order_detail',$data);
```

Comment: if i put id_sub[] in view order, its show nothing to do but if i input id_sub its work but still 1 data insert not for array. can tell me how my code?